# Split Pandas dataframe by a specific custom parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample pandas dataframe as below:

[image]

What I want to do is to write a function to split this dataframe by its time value. The function returns a list of dataframes.

I used the below function to split the dataframe.

```
def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size=20):
    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
    return chunks
```

However, this function splits the dataframe by its number of rows equally. In this case, it's 20 by default. What I want to achieve is to get dataframe every 3 seconds (or x seconds). For instance, get the first dataframe where we have rows in 300 and 303 seconds, then the next dataframe will be in 304 to 307 seconds, and so on. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

What I have done is create a new column that displays yes or no if the time is in the 3 seconds. But that did not help much.

Also, please note that I might have multiple ids, and time is always increasing. It could also be the same. Normally, time values are very precise and include decimals. I just cast those to int. So, in this case, the dataframes might not be the same size.
I would appreciate it if you could help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
        "sample_val": [10, 11, 10, 12, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24],
        "time": [300, 301, 301, 302, 302, 304, 311, 308, 309, 305],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
N = 3

df = df.sort_values(by="time")

intervals = [[i, i + N] for i in range(df["time"].min(), df["time"].max(), N + 1)]
# [[300, 303], [304, 307], [308, 311]]

# Find rows that belong to the same interval
chunks = df.apply(
    lambda x: [interval[0] <= x["time"] <= interval[1] for interval in intervals].index(
        True
    ),
    axis=1,
)

# Split df accordingly
dfs = [df_.reset_index(drop=True) for _, df_ in df.groupby(chunks)]
```

Then:

```py
print(dfs[0])
# Output
   id  sample_val  time
0   1          10   300
1   1          11   301
2   1          10   301
3   2          12   302
4   2          22   302

print(dfs[1])
# Output
   id  sample_val  time
0   3          22   304
1   5          24   305

print(dfs[2])
# Output
   id  sample_val  time
0   4          23   308
1   5          24   309
2   4          23   311
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question though: `..index(True)` gives error as "True" is not in the list. .index method takes value, start and stop. Not sure what to put there.

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify start or stop. I can't reproduce your issue. In your real code, is the dataframe modified after defining `intervals` but before defining `chunks`?

Comment: It was a different issue of mine.